# Can't remove messages from chat view controller when switching to another chat

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Below is my viewDidAppear function which successfully loads all previous messages only the first time the user opens a chat. After that, when the user exits a chat then starts another, the messages from the previous chat load at the top with those specific to the most recent chat being added to the end of these messages. Clearly not ideal. I tried to remove all messages from the messages array when clicking the chatVC's back button to exit (as shown below), but that causes the app to crash when attempting to load the new chat. Specifically, it crashes on the override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
} (also shown below).

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if presentedChatVCFromChatListVC{
        chatRef.child(chatListingID).child("messages").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            print("snapshot.value is \(snapshot.value)")
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let childData = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                print("childData is \(childData)")
                if let dict = childData.value as? NSDictionary{
                    let mediaType = dict["MediaType"] as! String
                    let senderId = dict["senderId"] as! String
                    let senderName = dict["senderName"] as! String

                    self.observeUsers(senderId)
                    switch mediaType {

                    case "TEXT":

                        let text = dict["text"] as! String
                        self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, text: text))
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()

                    case "PHOTO":

                        let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: nil)
                        let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as! String
                        let downloader = SDWebImageDownloader.shared()
                        downloader.downloadImage(with: URL(string: fileUrl)!, options: [], progress: nil, completed: { (image, data, error, finished) in
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                photo?.image = image
                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            })
                        })

                        self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))
                        if self.senderId == senderId {
                            photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                        }else{
                            photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                        }

                    case "VIDEO":

                        let fileUrl = dict["fileUrl"] as! String
                        let video = URL(string: fileUrl)!
                        let videoItem = JSQVideoMediaItem(fileURL: video, isReadyToPlay: true)
                        self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: videoItem))

                        if self.senderId == senderId {
                            videoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                        } else {
                            videoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                        }

                    default:
                        print("unknown data type")

                    }
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }else{
        chatRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "otherUserID").queryEqual(toValue: otherUID).observe(.value, with:{
                snapshot in
            print("snapshot.value is \(snapshot.value)")
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let childData = child as! FIRDataSnapshot
                print("childData is \(childData)")
                if let dict = childData.value as? NSDictionary{
                    let temp = dict["userID"] as! String
                    if temp == userID{
                        chatListingID = dict["chatRoomKey"] as! String
                        self.chatRef.child(chatListingID).child("messages").observe(.value, with:{
                            snapshot in
                            for child1 in snapshot.children {
                                let childData1 = child1 as! FIRDataSnapshot
                                print("childData1 is \(childData1)")
                                if let dict1 = childData1.value as? NSDictionary{
                                    let mediaType = dict1["MediaType"] as! String
                                    let senderId = dict1["senderId"] as! String
                                    let senderName = dict1["senderName"] as! String

                                    self.observeUsers(senderId)
                                    switch mediaType {

                                    case "TEXT":

                                        let text = dict1["text"] as! String
                                        self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, text: text))
                                        self.collectionView.reloadData()

                                    case "PHOTO":

                                        let photo = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: nil)
                                        let fileUrl = dict1["fileUrl"] as! String
                                        let downloader = SDWebImageDownloader.shared()
                                        downloader.downloadImage(with: URL(string: fileUrl)!, options: [], progress: nil, completed: { (image, data, error, finished) in
                                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                                photo?.image = image
                                                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                            })
                                        })

                                        self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: photo))
                                        if self.senderId == senderId {
                                            photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                                        }else{
                                            photo?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                                        }

                                    case "VIDEO":

                                        let fileUrl = dict1["fileUrl"] as! String
                                        let video = URL(string: fileUrl)!
                                        let videoItem = JSQVideoMediaItem(fileURL: video, isReadyToPlay: true)
                                        self.messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderId, displayName: senderName, media: videoItem))

                                        if self.senderId == senderId {
                                            videoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = true
                                        } else {
                                            videoItem?.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
                                        }

                                    default:
                                        print("unknown data type")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
    observeTyping()
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
}
func backButtonDidClick(){
    self.messages.removeAll()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Also, adding "self.collectionView.reloadData()" after "self.messages.removeAll()" results in going to a different chat incorrectly starting out blank. A little better than crashing, but not much. How do I clear the messages so changing who the user messages results in the chat view controller only loading that user's messages and not the ones previously loaded or none at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have put all of your logic in the `viewDidAppear` this method is not called as often as your are assuming here. so when you navigate some where else the view is not being destroyed making it quicker when you come back to it. You should move this logic out into another function. Only put things in the `viewDidAppear` that setup the view I.E. setting the background color. You probably want this logic to be in your `viewDidLoad()` that will have allot more of the behavior you are looking for.